# Mesh is on the inside of the object in certain areas?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

When I am zoomed in on the object the mesh seems to go inside of the object.

[image]

In a more zoomed out view you can start to see the mesh again.
I have changed the 'start' clipping distance to 0.001, however this doesn't seem to affect it very much.
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Here is the file:
[image]

Comment: so maybe hide some faces to check if there are some unwanted inner faces?

Comment: I hid some faces but there are no doubles. I have already used merge by distance so there are no unwanted duplicate vertices

Comment: Don't worry, nothing wrong. This is just how Blender displays vertices. Turn off the subdivision surface modifier temporarily if it annoys you. You can also show the modifier in edit mode.

Comment: you didn't share the same object as the one we see

Comment: The reason I feel as if something is wrong is because in the tutorial I can see this happening to andrew aswell although not as bad. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ViVKUiG8ks&list=PLjEaoINr3zgHJVJF3T3CFUAZ6z11jKg6a&index=5

Comment: as Leander says the shading looks normal

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got a subsurf modifier enabled. You can disable it in edit mode so that the subdivided mesh doesn't block you from seeing the wireframe.

[image]