# Why do my vertices fade the further I zoom in?

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view, vertices, faces

I have tried adjusting clipping value but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I have to constantly go into x-ray mode in order to edit the mesh to see the lines. If I zoom out the lines are there and visible but it's too hard to make changes when that zoomed out to minor details. Any clue?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? -- https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178854/mesh-is-on-the-inside-of-the-object-in-certain-areas?rq=1

Comment: [How do I stop vertices being hidden by the Subsurf modifier in Edit mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107791/how-do-i-stop-vertices-being-hidden-by-the-subsurf-modifier-in-edit-mode)

Comment: @Timaroberts I don't see it as duplication. Main question here is pointed to zoom in/out effect. Provided link describes how to disable modifier to see wire. BTW this "dupli" link now direct to another closed link as dupli. Doesn't seems to be a nice let user run this marathon :) Thank you

Comment: Re your "marathon" @vklidu See eg. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material Consider that duplicates are not a bad thing, it always helps to keep the site organized in case the same information can be found on different places. No matter if this question is about zoomin in and out, the answer is the still same (IMHO).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason why the actual wire is partially hidden is because the actual geometry is affected by the *Subdivision Surface Modifier* and you see a modified version of the mesh, even in *Edit Mode*.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html

[image]

I'd suggest go to the *Modifier Panel* and enable 'On Cage' option of the *Subdivision Surface Modifier* by clicking the little **triangle icon**

[image]

or just **disable the modifier** temporary in order to affect how the mesh is visualized in *Edit Mode*.

[image]

---

The reason why zoom in/out affects those "fading" vertices is because blender is displaying partially wire inside of a mesh to improve viewport experience for vertices that would be quickly hidden in sharp angle view. This "inside" view is constant for viewport, but actual distances of vertices in viewport are changing.

[image]